# Please help me understand Pusher websocket API in Java

Tags: java, channel, pusher

I would like to use a Pusher Websocket connection using the [official Java library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client). I got basic features running, like connecting it to a data service and receiving messages. However, I'm having a hard time implementing other features, like reading the status of the connection. Maybe you can help me by answering some of these questions:

1) What happens when initiating a pusher and connecting it to a service(pusher.connect())? Is the connected pusher running in a separate thread?

2) How can I get the current state of my pusher-connection?

3) If my pusher is updating an object that is in parallel used by other services, can this cause problems?

4) How can I handle errors/exceptions? So far I haven't received any, would an error look like a normal exception or is it handled differently?

Thanks!

Below I copied my current code. Please note that the while-loop at the bottom is only used for testing so that the code keeps running.

```
import com.pusher.client.Pusher;
import com.pusher.client.channel.Channel;
import com.pusher.client.channel.ChannelEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionState;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionStateChange;


public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        // Create a new Pusher instance
        Pusher pusher = new Pusher("PusherKey");

        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                System.out.println("State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() +
                                   " from " + change.getPreviousState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("There was a problem connecting!");
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        // Subscribe to a channel
         Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("channel", new ChannelEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName) {
                 System.out.println("Subscribed!");
             }

             @Override
             public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, String data) {
                 System.out.println("desilo se");
             }
         });

         // Bind to listen for events called "my-event" sent to "my-channel"
         channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
                 System.out.println("Received event with data: " + data);
             }
         });

        while(true){
            try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
            }

        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What happens when initiating a pusher and connecting it to a service(pusher.connect())? Is the connected pusher running in a separate thread?

You can see thread management and interaction in the two following files:

- [`WebSocketConnection`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pusher/client/connection/websocket/WebSocketConnection.java)`
- [`Factory`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client/blob/1a302364e4c3c96884af8d23ed3a9f68d9a57e4a/src/main/java/com/pusher/client/util/Factory.java)

So, interaction with the underlying WebSocket connection take place within a designated queue (named `eventQueue`).

> 2) How can I get the current state of my pusher-connection?

```
ConnectionState state = pusher.getConnection.getState();
```

> 3) If my pusher is updating an object that is in parallel used by other services, can this cause problems?

If you have a multi-threaded application you would need to manage access to shared objects yourself.

All interaction with code outside of the library (your code) takes place on the `eventQueue` thread.

> 4) How can I handle errors/exceptions? So far I haven't received any, would an error look like a normal exception or is it handled differently?

Where possible and appropriate the Pusher Java client library will catch exceptions and provide them to your code via a callback e.g. `ConnectionEventListener.onError`.

In any situation where exceptions take place that are not handled by the library you'll know since your IDE will tell you that your not handling an exception case/your code won't compile e.g. [`Pusher.connect` @throws](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client/blob/57dfbc233fea5cdf62177793697304aed505e6b4/src/main/java/com/pusher/client/Pusher.java#L120)

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. About question 4), how does a callback look like or how can I handle it? It sounds like a callback will just "pop up" in case something happened.

Comment: @user3116232 I believe you've found the JavaDocs. But to answer your questions - it's here: http://pusher.github.io/pusher-java-client/com/pusher/client/connection/ConnectionEventListener.html